# (UNITY2D) problema de variable "speed" de movimiento

Tags: c#, unity, unity2d

Mi problema es que no puedo incrementar la velocidad de el objeto llegado a un punto, puede bajar pero no incrementar, esta velocidad va ligada a la variable "speed" pero por más que modifique no aumenta.

Trato de mover el "rd2d" el cual es el personaje con el siguiente código:

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour {

```
public float speed = 9000f;

Animator anim; 
Rigidbody2D rbd2; 
Vector2 mov;



void Start()  {


   
    rbd2 = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();


}


void Update() {

    mov = new Vector2(

        Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),
        Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")       
        ); 
}

void FixedUpdate () {

    rbd2.MovePosition(rbd2.position + mov * speed * Time.deltaTime);

}
```

}

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: creo simplemente agrega un parentesis para separar el vector de movimiento del factor de incremento.   rbd2.MovePosition((rbd2.position + mov) * speed * Time.deltaTime);